# Autoloading class files for PHPUnit

Tags: php, composer-php, phpunit

So, I am just playing around with PHPUnit, I don't really need it but I want to learn how it works so I am trying it out on a random class in a plugin of mine.
The issue I have rn is that whenever I run `phpunit` I says the `Plot` class in my test was not found. In my composer.json file I have

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },

    "autoload":{
        "psr-4" : { "\\mohagames\\PlotArea\\utils\\" : "src/mohagames/PlotArea/utils/"}
    }
}
```

And my Plot.php file is in the C:\Users\moham\Documents\GitHub\PlotArea\src\mohagames\PlotArea\utils\ directory and has the `mohagames\PlotArea\utils` namespace

But for some reason it still says

```
C:\Users\moham\Documents\GitHub\PlotArea>C:\Users\moham\Documents\Github\PlotArea\vendor\bin\phpunit --debug
PHPUnit 8.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.3.4
Configuration: C:\Users\moham\Documents\GitHub\PlotArea\phpunit.xml

Test 'SampleTest::testPlot' started
Test 'SampleTest::testPlot' ended


Time: 95 ms, Memory: 4.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) SampleTest::testPlot
Error: Class 'Plot' not found

C:\Users\moham\Documents\GitHub\PlotArea\tests\unit\SampleTest.php:8

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

And the SampleTest test class:

```php
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SampleTest extends TestCase{

    public function testPlot(){
        $plot = new Plot();

    }
}
```

I've tried all sort of solutions on the internet but none of them worked

Comment: What is the full namespace to the Plot class?  You've not imported it (with a 'use' at the top of the file, or \with\a\fullpath\Plot)

Comment: Thank you very much! I really don't know how I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Alister pointed out importing the class first works otherwise, PHP doesn't know what class the code is referring to.

```php
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use mohagames\PlotArea\utils\Plot;

class SampleTest extends TestCase{

    public function testPlot(){
        $plot = new Plot();

    }
}
```